# Updating phpMyAdmin that works with MySQL 5.1.73

Tags: mysql

I have recently setup a Xen VPS hosting (CentOS 6/512MB RAM/20GB HDD) for my WordPress based website. My current phpMyAdmin version is 4.1.7 and the current MySQL version is 5.1.73.

I wanted to update my phpMyAdmin to the latest version but I'm told it requires MySQL 5.5. I was advised against updating MySQL to 5.5 due to some security issues. Hence, which is the latest version of phpMyAdmin that is supported by MySQL 5.1.73?

Comment: Latest is 5.7. I haven't seen anything worse in CVEs (always "unspecified vulnerability") for 5.5 than any other; 5.1 is nearing end of life. Any source for this assertion that 5.1 is more secure?

Comment: MySQL 5.5 likely fixes more security issues than it causes. I'd question the vague assertion that it has "some security issues" from your unknown expert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4.0.x (currently 4.0.10), which will be supported (for security fixes) until January 1, 2015. See http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php for information -- under each version there is a brief description of what the requirements are and how long it will be supported, and the 4.0.x branch is currently the best choice for your situation.

I agree with the others that I'm not aware of any unfixed security issues in 5.5; in fact as dartonw mentioned since 5.1 is nearing the end of life they won't be fixing any vulnerabilities found in that, so you'll need to upgrade sometime. You might want to get more specifics on the vulnerabilities you were advised about.